# Run "Repeatagent" on Xpage

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I would like the following agent to run onclick of a button,  the agents job is to check if the user wants a document(in this case a Journal Entry) to be date repetetive. So I am trying to create multiple documents at once. I had a simular Lotusscript running in the Notes Application which seemed to work fine but I dont know how to run it on my Xpage.
Code:

```
Sub Initialize
Dim session As New NotesSession 
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim UIdoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim doc As NotesDocument 
Dim Workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set UIdoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
Dim Radio As String
Dim String1 As String
Dim Counter As Integer
Print("Repeat Agent Triggered and Variables Initialized")
String1 = UIdoc.FieldGetText("SubjectTX")
Radio = UIdoc.FieldGetText( "RepeatValueTX" )
Dim ret As Variant 
Dim Newdate As New NotesDateTime(UIdoc.FieldGetText("DiaryDateDT")) 
Print(Radio)
Print(String1)
Print("Select Case...")
Select Case Radio
    Case "Day": 
        Print("Case Day in use")
        For Counter = 1 To 7
            Call Newdate.AdjustDay( 1 )
            Set doc = db.CreateDocument
            doc.SubjectTX = "Day Revision " + String1
            doc.DiaryDateDT = NewDate
            Call doc.Save( True, True )
        Next
    Case "Week":
        Print("Case Week in use")
        For Counter = 1 To 4
            Call Newdate.AdjustDay( 7 )
            Set doc = db.CreateDocument
            doc.SubjectTX = "Week Revision:" + String1
            doc.DiaryDateDT = NewDate
            Call doc.Save( True, True )
        Next
    Case Else: 
        Print("No Case or Saving and Closing")
End Select
   Print("exited switch, Saving and Closing now")
   Call UIdoc.Save()
   Call UIdoc.Close()
```

End Sub

The Agent is set to "Allow restricted operations" , "Run as Web user" , Target:none, "Agent List selection".

The Javascript supposed to execute the Agent

```
database.getAgent("Repeatagent").run()
```

maybe I am missing something essential here, if there is a better way to do this please let me know!

I am fairly new to notes and sort of bunched this together from the help menu so if you have a solution please try to explain very extensive.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to translate this agent to a [Java Bean](http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/creating-your-first-managed-bean-for-xpages.html) and call it directly from your Xpage's querysave event.

If you still like the lotusscript agent, then you need to change the UI classes to backend (NotesUIDocument -> NotesDocument) as you do not have access to NotesUIWorkspace in backendagent. In this case, have a look at passing the [documentcontext](http://blog.nashcom.de/nashcomblog.nsf/dx/passing-a-document-to-an-agent-without-saving-it-first.htm) to an agent

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues you need to address:

- agents to be triggered on a server can only contain backend classes. Your agent contains uidoc which is NotesClient only
- you try to get values from ui classes

If you want to save yourself a big headache you rewrite that code in JavaScript or Java as a simple function. You have session and database as top level objects. Call them from a button on the XPage and hand over the value as parameters.